# How to make the small notification count next to an element

Tags: html, css

I have this following html tag

```html
<li style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
     <b><span class="need-confirm-number" style="/*height: 15px;*/ display: inline;">0</span></b>
     <a href="#" class="text-dark">My Submitted Requests</a>
</li>
```

I would like to make the notification count (b tag) appears to the left of the anchor tag? How would I do that?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. It's to the left of the anchor tag with the code you currently have.

Comment: It is to the left but above the anchor tag element, I would like it to appear exactly to the left of the anchor tag

Comment: This is not apparent from the code you provided. Please provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<li style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);position:relative;">
     <span class="need-confirm-number" style="position:absolute; top: -5px; left: 5px; height: 15px;padding: 2px;display: inline-block; background:#ff0000; color:#fff; border-radius: 5px;"><b>0</b></span>
     <a href="#" class="text-dark">My Submitted Requests</a>
</li>
```

you may need something like this. this code may need  many improvements. but you can get the idea from this. so basically your parent tag needs to be `position:relative;` then you make your notification counter `position:absolute;`and you correctly position it and design it.